# Regex string to only keep lines with certain varying criteria java

Tags: java, regex, criteria

I have a text file in which I want to pull only 3 integers (some negative) per line from. The lines where integers occur **all end in the same fashion (,world)**, **however not all of the lines in the text file contain these integers**. Three lines from this file where the integers reside, as well as two lines that do not have desirable integers, are as follows:

```
[16:22:99] [Client thread/INFO]: lorem ipsum
[17:30:23] [Client thread/INFO]: 108, 46, 646, world
[17:30:23] [Client thread/INFO]: -1000, 39, 719, world
[17:30:23] [Client thread/INFO]: 927, 63, -1, world
[18:42:19] [Client thread/INFO]: dolor sit amet
```

The result I want from this is simply:

```
108, 46, 646
-1000, 39, 719
927, 63, -1
```

**Note that the integer sizes may range from 1-4**.

At the present I have the following code which is crude, but works after refining the text file to include only those lines with the desired integers (an ineffective process):

```
String all = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("loc.txt")));
all = all.replace("[17:30:23] [Client thread/INFO]: [CHAT] ", "");
all = all.replace(", world", "");
all = all.replace(" ", "");
locArray = all.split("\\r?\\n");
```

This adds only the 3 integer triplet into the desired string array, however I want to be able to extract the integers without having to edit the text file.

My question is: *How would one use regex to leave only the 3-digit triplet into the String array, including the occasional negative symbol, despite some lines having no triplets at all?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could try something like this:

```
((-?\d+(,\s)?)+)(?=,\sworld)\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/yB9hX2/3

It matches the comma-separated digits, including negatives, up until `world`.  If a line doesn't match, it ignores it.  It uses a positive lookahead to ensure that the digits are followed by `world`.

Comment: This appears to be brilliant, however being the novice at Regex I am, could you edify me a bit on how exactly I would go about using your code?

Comment: I don't do much Java but you should be able to iterate the lines, use regex to test the line for a match and return the first capture group. Let me look for an example.

Comment: Excellent, thanks I'll try that logic now and check back to see if your example is more efficient.

Comment: Update: By setting your pattern as a string and using a matcher I was able to get my desired result, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

<s>use this simple pattern to extract what you want</s>

```
(-?\d{1,4}, -?\d{1,4}, -?\d{1,4})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/266)

Per comment below use this pattern instead

```
(-?\d{1,4}, -?\d{1,4}, -?\d{1,4})(?=, world)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/269)

Comment: While this would get me what I need, the possibility exists that another 3 integer triplet may exist within the text file that does not end in ",world" (a triplet I do not want), hence why I would need only those integers whose lines end in ",world".

Comment: @BbJug, modified above

Comment: Marvelous, thank you. The other answer produces the same result, however could you enlighten me on how I would use your pattern to input the integer triplets into the string array?

Comment: don't know much about java, but in javascript : https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/269#javascript

Comment: Update: I did more research on java's Regex and used your pattern and a while loop with a matcher to get what I wanted, thanks for your answer!